# Heroku scheduler "Don't know how to build task 'update_lines'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

I have an app running on Heroku. I want to use the Scheduler add-on. I have followed instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler to no avail.

I have the following in db/lib/scheduler.rake

```
task :update_lines => :environment do
  puts "Updating lines..."
  Line.get_lines
  puts "done."
end
```

I have a class method in Line called get_lines.

The error when I do a `heroku run rake update_lines`

is "Don't know how to build task 'update_lines'"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be located at `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` as described in the linked article:

> For Rails, the convention is to set up rake tasks. To create your
>   scheduled tasks in Rails, copy the code below into
>   lib/tasks/scheduler.rake and customize it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The task needs to be defined in `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` instead of `db/lib/scheduler.rake` in order for rake to pick it up.

Comment: Wow... yeah... somehow I must have dragged /lib into /db.